# Как правильно вставить проверку на число в функцию суммы 2х чисел (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n))

Tags: javascript, функции

```
var x = +prompt("введите первое число","");
var y = +prompt("введите второе число","");

function sum(x,y)
 {
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(sum(x,y))) && isFinite(sum(x,y))){

return x+y;

}else {
alert("введите корректные числа");
}
}
alert(sum(x,y));
```

Тут скорее всего всё не правильно...Мне просто интересно нужно делать такую проверку по отдельности для каждого слагаемого(а если их 100 штук)? Или всё таки сразу для всей функции суммы можно сделать?

Comment: а это вообще не бесконечная рекурсия? В `sum(x,y)` безусловное вычисление `sum(x,y)`

Comment: Вобще  не совсем корректно  вопрос  поставил.. был такой пример:               var a = +prompt("Введите первое число", "");
var b = +prompt("Введите второе число", "");

alert( a + b );  И вот мне надо эту проверку !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)  как -то сделать.. так вот если бы слагаемых было бы не 2 а 100 мне ж  не делать её для каждого.. так как сделать её для функции суммы,хотя бы 2х слагаемых?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = +prompt("a", "");
var y = +prompt("b", "");

var z = x + y;

alert(isFinite(z) ? z : "Invalid or too large input");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isNumeric(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }
function sum(){
        var arg=arguments,
        x=!!1,
        req=0;
        arg.forEach(function(num){
            if(x){
                if(!isNumeric(num))x=!1;
                else
                req+=num;
            }
        });
        if(!x)return "введи числа!!";
        return req;
  }
```